# Want an alternate solution to this set theory Q

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, express each of the following sets in terms of $A$, $B$ and $C$, using the symbols $\cup$, $\cap$, and $-$.

$$F=\{x\mid x\in A\text{ and }(x\in B\implies x\in C)\}$$

**My solution:**

$x\in B\implies x\in C$

can be rewritten as

$\neg(x\in B)$ or $x\in C$

i.e. $x\notin B$ or $x\in C$

i.e. $x\in B^c$ or $x\in C$

$\begin{aligned}
F&=A\cap(B^c\cup C) \\
&=(A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap C) \\
&=(A-B)\cup(A\cap C)
\end{aligned}$

---

I don't like this solution as I have to introduce $B^c$ and the concept of a universal set, which we haven't covered in the textbook.

Can someone think of a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially what you've already written, but slightly rephrased:

First, we rewrite the condition for being in $F$ as $$(x\in A\mbox{ and }x\not\in B)\quad\mbox{or}\quad(x\in A\mbox{ and }x\in C).$$ Now we just note that the first disjunct is *exactly* the definition of "$x\in A-B$."