# How to deal with "If P, then Q" in the description of a set?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Here is the original question:

Given sets $A,B,C$ express the set in terms of A,B,C, using the symbols $\cup$,$\cap$, and $-$. $$F=\{x | x\in A\text{ and } (x\in  B) \rightarrow (x\in C)\}$$

I have found some solution like $A-(B-C),\,A\cap(B \cap C),\,(B \cap C)\cap A$. I do these all by trying, I wonder if there is a regular way to find or to judge whether I have found all the solution. Someone else give a more answer [(−)∪(∩)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640974/want-an-alternate-solution-to-this-set-theory-q) for the same question. Welcome edit if there is something unclear, thanks!

New add: Maybe an explanation for my second and third answers is necessary. Take the second one. If $x\in ∩(∩)$, it is trivially true that $x\in A$ and the both side of → is true because $x\in B, x\in C$. Above is my understanding, or I am wrong? Please point out. And if my second and third answers is right, my question will be different from which is suggested below.

Comment: What is $⋐$? Maybe $\in$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Right, sorry. I am not familiar with mathlax

Comment: As per linked question $P \to Q$ is $\lnot P \lor Q$. Thus, $x \in B \to x \in C$ is equivalent to $x \notin B \lor x \in C$

Comment: Your first solution is correct. Your second and third solutions are not correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want an alternate solution to this set theory Q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640974/want-an-alternate-solution-to-this-set-theory-q)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have add something, could you help to check? My question may be a little different from that.

Comment: $A \cap (B \cap C)$ is a part of $F$ (i.e. a subset) but it doesn't cover **all** the cases of $F$'s condition. $(B\cap C)\cap A$ is the same set again which is pointless.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I get it, thanks! about"→ is logically equivalent to  ¬∨", I think out some proof. I will put it in self-answer tomorrow as complement to your answer. can you check then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi \to \psi$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot \phi \lor \psi$.

So $$\{x\mid (x \in B) \to (x \in C\}$$ is then just the same as (with $\phi=(x \in B)$, $\psi=(x \in C)$  $$\{x\mid x \notin B \lor x \in C\}$$

which is $$B^\complement \cup C$$

The first clause of the definition of $F$ says $x \in A$ so we must *intersect* that set with $A$ and we get

$$A \cap (B^\complement \cup C) = (A \cap B^\complement) \cup (A \cap C)$$

(Using distributivity of $\cap$ over $\cup$)
But the question asks to use $-$ (for which I prefer $\setminus$ as a notation BTW) and then a little thought tells us that $A \cap B^\complement = A-B$ and so we get as answer $$(A-B) \cup (A \cap C)$$

This doesn't correspond directly to any of your suggested answers though.

Comment: $A-(B-C)=(A-B)\cup(A\cap C)$....

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I said *directly*. Your statement requires extra steps.

Comment: I don't think the question was about explaining how the expression in the link was obtained. The OP seems to be asking for other equal expressions using $-,\cap,\cup$ and how to obtain them.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I add my explanation in the question, can you help to check? And  I am puzzled about "→ is logically equivalent to  ¬∨".

Comment: @CHENWONG what’s your background in logic? It’s basically the **definition** of $\phi \to \psi$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am very sorry about that. I just start to learn logic myself for serval days. I am reading the book Topology(munkres) , and the problem is from that. But before the problem I didn't see a definition like that. In which field I can find that?

Comment: @CHENWONG if $phi$ does not hold, the implication holds voidly by definition. Or else $\phi$ holds and then $\psi$ must hold. So when $\lnot phi \lor \psi$ holds Sofies the implication. Or think about falsifying the implication and the apply De Morgan.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what's "Sofies"? and I agree that your answer is correct , but what about my other answers?

Comment: @CHENWONG a typo. Of your other answers only the first is maybe correct but requires an argument. You cannot just guess an answer.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh, I have added my explanation. could you help to check? I just guess some answers and find it satisfy(maybe, in my opinion, so I add explanation) the statement for F